# Plot an anonymous function without explicit variable names

Tags: matlab, plot, anonymous-function

I created an anonymous function handle like this:

```
 f = @(x,y)sqr(x)+sqr(y)
```

This is a sphere with the two variables `x` and `y`. It seems to work since I can call something like

```
f(2,3)
```

and MATLAB gives me the right result `ans = 13`.

In the last step I want to plot that function from let's say -7 to 7 for both `x` and `y`. So I call

```
fmesh(f,[-7 7])
```

and the right figure pops up. So far, so good.

For some reasons, which I don't wanna specify here, I now want to edit the function handle to this:

```
f = @(x)sqr(x(1))+sqr(x(2))
```

This should be the same sphere but this time with the 2 variables `x(1)` and `x(2)`.
Since the function now wants an array as argument I edited the test call

```
f([2,3])
```

and it still gives me the right result `ans = 13`.

But here is the problem: How do you plot the function that wants an array as argument? 
The same mesh command as before of course fails, since `[-7,7]` has the wrong dimension. The same goes for `[[-7 7] [-7 7]]` and `[[-7 7];[-7 7]]`.

How can I get a working plot from that new function handle?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't really do that. You could wrap `f` inside of another anonymous function which accepts two inputs and creates one: `g = @(x,y)f([x,y])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get `fmesh` to pass the `x` and `y` values as an array like what you expect. What you *can* do is to wrap your anonymous function `f` within another anonymous function which simply re-arranges the input.

```
g = @(x,y)f([x, y]);
fmesh(g, [-7 7])
```

A more generalized solution which takes all inputs and puts them into an array would be

```
g = @(varargin)f([varargin{:}])
```